# How do you calculate this

Tags: javascript, math, operators

```js
var x = 5;
x *= 2;
console.log(++x);
```

How is the answer 11? I'm confused

Comment: What result did you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x = 5; // x = 5
x *= 2; // multiply x with 2 (x = 10)
console.log(++x); // console.log x plus 1 (11)
```

A more common way of using this syntax is with plus or minus:

```
x += 1;
// is a shorthand for
x = x + 1;

x *= 2;
// is a shorthand for
x = x * 2;

// etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

`++x` increments FIRST, and THEN is used, vs:
`x++` which is used FIRST, THEN is incremented.

if `x` is `10`,
`console.log(++x)` will result in "11", vs:
`console.log(x++)` will result in "10".

In both cases, after code line, `x` will be `11`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x = 5;
x *= 2;
console.log(x);
console.log(++x);
```

`x *= 2;` says: *`x` will be reinitialised (reassigned) to what it was before (`5`) multiplied by `2` (which gives us `10`)*. ([Useful link - look at chapter Modify-in-place](https://javascript.info/operators))

`++x` says: *`x` will be reinitialised (reassigned) to what it was before (`10`) plus `1`. Also, return `x`s new value (`11`)*. ([In same link, look at the below chapter Increment/Decrement](https://javascript.info/operators))

If, instead, we had `x++` it'll say: *'add 1 to x but don't return this new value - return the value before we made this addition (`10`)*:

```js
var x = 5;
x *= 2;
console.log(x++);
```